# Use E4X with jrunscript?

Tags: javascript, xml, rhino, e4x

I use jrunscript for some JavaScript. Works like a charm. Now I wanted to use E4X in JRunScript. The following statements should work:

```
var x = <hello />;
var y = new XML();
```

but I get:

```
js> var x = <hello />;
script error: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException:
syntax error (<STDIN>#1) in <STDIN> at line number 1
js> var x = new XML(); 
script error: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError:
ReferenceError: "XML" is not defined. (<STDIN>#1) in <STDIN> at line number 1
js>
```

Poking around I found references to xmlbeans.jar as prerequisite, but xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar is in lib/ext.

```
java -version :
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux x86-32
jrunscript -q :
Language ECMAScript 1.6 implemention "Mozilla Rhino" 1.6 release 2
```

So what do I miss that E4X isnt't available in my jrunscript?

Comment: The space before the self-closing slash isn't necessary unless you were writing HTML, not XML.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsengine), specifically:

> **E4X (ECMAScript for XML - ECMA Standard 357) has been excluded**. Use of
>   an XML literal in JavaScript code will result in a syntax error. Note
>   that E4X support is optional in the ECMAScript standard - a
>   implementation can omit E4X support and still be a compliant
>   ECMAScript implementation.

Comment: I know it is optional and I know that it is in the Mozilla Rhino implementation. What I'm looking for is how to get my JVM/JKD to use the Mozilla Rhino implementation instead of the default JDK implementation when running jrunscript

Comment: You cannot substiture the full Mozilla Rhino for the stripped down version when running the jrunscript that ships with JREs/JDKs. jrunscript is nothing more than a wrapper for the stripped down Mozilla Rhino and that can't be changed without rewriting jrunscript.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the correct JavaScript version before running your script by either calling `version(160)` or using the `-version 160` launch flag. You would also be able to use 180 (JavaScript 1.8) if you updated Rhino to a much more recent version.

Comment: Hi Eli,
thx for stopping by. Could you elaborate more on the use of version(160) or -version 160; I tried "jrunscript -version 160" but got an error also -Dversion=160 didn't help. And "version(160);" is unknown to my Rhino runtime. When I do "jrunscript -q" I get "Language ECMAScript 1.6 implemention "Mozilla Rhino" 1.6 release 2". Suggestions?

Comment: I'm talking about Rhino itself, not `jrunscript`. Just run Rhino with that flag.

Comment: Hi Eli, you might have missed my first sentence: "I use **jrunscript** for some JavaScript. Works like a charm. Now I wanted to use E4X in **JRunScript**."